# Excel Macro not sorting correctly

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have this script and it sorts MT-001 - MT-999 recently I added two more entries "MT-1000" and "MT-1001" and this is how my Macro is sorting.....

```
MT-099
MT-100
MT-1000
MT-1001
MT-102
MT-103
```

My macro for sorting is the following:

```
Sub FILTERMT()
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*MT*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A7:BZ65536").Sort Key1:=Range("B6"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End Sub
```

Can someone post a code that corrects this error? THX for contributing to this community!

Comment: Do you have the possibility to add a 3rd column to your sheet, or is the design of columns fixed?

Comment: @David: As I understand, the problem is the string sort. Isn't standard A-Z exactly string sort? The OP would like to sort numerical. So my suggestion would be to extract the numbers to a 3rd column and then to sort after this column.

Comment: I misspoke, twice :) My first comment (which I deleted inadvertently) is correct: this **is** standard sort for string. OP could use a helper column like you suggest. Or other methods...

Comment: @FreeMan, this is not a request for code site.  This question is a request for code and refusing to answer such questions is definitely what you are supposed to do on this site.

Comment: wow! I did not wish to cause conflict but thanks for the comments..... good thing someone posted a good solution. <thumbs up>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice, `MT-099` has a leading zero to ensure it sorts before `MT-100` while `MT-102` does not have a leading zero to ensure it sorts before `MT-1000`.

You will need to modify your data to support 4-digit, left zero-padded numbers, or come up with a way to split the numeric portion off into a different column for sorting purposes.

Comment: Thank you! I sorted "MT-0001" - "MT-1001" and the macro sorted it properly!

Answer (score 2):

Choose a 3rd column, that may even be a many columns to the right if necessary.

Fill the cells of this column with this formula:

```
=RIGHT(B6;LEN(B6)-FIND("-");B6))*1
```

Here, I assume that the top of your list ("MT-099") ist at field B6.

The `right` expression cuts the number out of the string. The `*1` is to really convert to a number. You need only the number treated as a number in order to sort the right way.

Se the formula e.g. in C6 and copy the content downwards to the end row of your list.

Then simply alter your code; here I assume that your new column is C:

```
Range("A7:BZ65536").Sort Key1:=Range("C6"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
    xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

To clarify, here is how it looks like after sorting:

[image]

If necessary, you may narrow your 3rd column to zero length, so it is invisible.

Comment: @Steve IT: Just to add to this. What you're experiencing is happening because excel is treating it as text, hence 0 comes before 1. You want it to sort numerically

Comment: @pnuts haha thanks. I meant in a textual context which is why he's got 1001 then 101. But in guessing you knew that ;)

Comment: @peter_the_oak  Thank you! I had already considered this but I wanted to sort using a macro. I see it is quite difficult to do this so I'll stick with this method...... Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help :-) This solution is a useful combination of macros and the comfort of designing cells. You could consider creating the key column dynamically by VBA and remove it after. However the real elegant solution would be if one could give an own sort function as parameter for `Range.Sort()`. Good luck.