# Excel is sorting a 3 digit combination numer before a 2 digit

Tags: excel

The following is a list of mine I am trying to sort out. The problem is that Excel is sorting it based on what I assume is the asce characters, therefore 130 is "less" than 14. Is there a VBA function to fix this? I have attempted to change the formatting to text, numbers, decimals, etc. but nothing seems to work. and it is case sensitive so I cannot input a 0 before the 14, as much as I would like to!

This is how excel sorts the numbers:

- 2A-130.1
- 2A-14
- 2A-150.1
- 2A-22
- 2A-22
- 2A-22
- 2A-41
- 2A-86
- 2A-86
- 2C-12

This is what I am looking for:

- 2A-14
- 2A-22
- 2A-22
- 2A-22
- 2A-41
- 2A-86
- 2A-86
- 2A-130.1
- 2A-150.1
- 2C-12

EDIT::: After attempting to use the helper column, this is now what the data looks like

- 2C-12
- 2A-14
- 2A-22
- 2A-22
- 2A-22
- 2A-41
- 2A-86
- 2A-86
- 2A-130.1

Using the Helper column that looks like this:

- 12
- 14
- 22
- 22
- 22
- 41
- 86
- 86
- 130.1

using this formula `=RIGHT(B2,(LEN(B2))-FIND("-",B2,1)*1)`

As you can tell the C comes before A, because now it is sorting it exclusively by the number. The page referenced in the comments helped a great deal, but those had a constant variable they were referring to where as mine can be any alphabetical letter following the numerical.

Comment: FYI this is called [natural sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148321/excel-macro-not-sorting-correctly/29148788#29148788

Comment: @FreeMan It is similar, yes, but that thread was resolved by adding 0's so all the numbers had the same amount of places. My data is case sensitive and thus cannot have 014 in place of 14.

Comment: In that case, it may be necessary to use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29149069/2344413) to that question.

Comment: In cases like that I use a helper column next to the data. In it I add the oh-so-useful zeroes, sort on *that* column so that the data I'm interested in gets pulled along for the ride, then hide or delete the helper column.

EDIT: On refresh, what FreeMan said in his second comment.

Comment: @FreeMan I took both your comments and attempted to use that link, unfortunately now it is sorting the numbers correctly, but since 2C-12 is in there It is sorting that ahead of some of the A's. any ideas?

Comment: Update your OP to show how all relevant columns you now have the data arranged into.

Comment: I was hoping you'd include the helper columns and how you've got them sorting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [Dubison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788015/2344413) posted, but slightly different. His presumes that the starting digit will always be `2`, while this will work no matter what the starting digit is (including a multi-digit value like 37):

The data and the sort setup:
[image]

The sort dialog box:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to desired result with following formulas:

My worksheet layout is like this:

[image]

and formulas:

**B1:** `=MID(A1,2,1)`
(Just to get the letter, you can retrieve it with several methods)

**C1:** `=IFERROR(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)),FIND(".",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)),1),1,","),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)))`
(To get the numbers and convert "." to "," which is my decimal separator)

then I applied "Custom Sort" under "Sort and Filter" as follows:

[image]

and if you get any warning:

[image]

if everything goes well you should get the result like:

[image]